# Jquery chosen update appending selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have looked everywhere for this, and all I am getting is stuff about dynamically appending more options.

I have a function that calls the following:

```
$("#" + id_name).val(result).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

this is called when clicking a suggested button, which then is supposed to **add** it to the `chosen-container-multi` container that has all the inputs and so on.

If I call the function again, it erases the previous result and puts the new one in that field. This container is supposed to be able to hold **multiple** results. **How could I go about doing this such that it appends the result to the prior results rather than replace it?**

Comment: Could you post the code for the function that is being called when the trigger fires?

Comment: The code I posted is the only code in that function. It takes parameter `result` and `id_name`, and then calls the one line I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/16Lj1whL/2/

```
function addValue(id_name,result)
{
    $s=$('#'+id_name);    
    $s.find('option[value="'+result+'"]').prop('selected',true);

    $s.trigger("chosen:updated");
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks. If you could write a brief explanation of why this works, that would be great!

Comment: $s.find('option[value="'+result+'"]') **//find option with value equal result**
.prop('selected',true); **//and selects it**

Comment: ah, so this is the same as if somebody clicked on it rather than just changing the value! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [.prop( propertyName, function )](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function)

```
$("#" + id_name).prop("value", function(_, val) {
  return val + result
}).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

```js
var input = $("input")
    , result = 0
, update = function() {
        input.prop("value", function (_, val) {
        return val + ++result
    })  
  };


$("button").on("click", update)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<input type="text" value="0">
```